# Nonmonotone functions in compact convex space

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions, multivalued-functions, monotone-class-theorem

I am asking for more explaining about :
If we have a function $
F\mathrm{(}x\mathrm{)}
$
 which is not monotone in $
x
$

And then we can say that the function :

$
\overline{F}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}{F}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{+}}{Mx}
$
 For $
{M}\mathrm{{>}}{0}
$

is monotone nondecreasing .

Or the function is monotone:

$
\overline{F}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}{F}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{-}}{Mx}
$
For
$
{M}\mathrm{{>}}{0}
$

nonincreasing
Where the functions are compact and convex functions in closed interval.

Comment: What does it mean for a *function* to be compact? I find no reference on the internet (at least in the first page of results). Did you mean something else? If $F(x) = x^2$ on $[-1,1]$ qualifies, then the answer is obviously "No", as $M$ has to be much bigger than $0$ before those functions become monotone.

Comment: Thanks . İf the function has two variables , would the result  change ?

Comment: Since you have not yet explained what you mean by a *function* being "compact", I can't say. But as far as my example goes, It works in any number of dimensions. For large enough $M$, the functions might be monotone, but for $M$ near $0$, they will not be.

Comment: @PaulSinclair i want to say that the functions defined in compact spaces but i but M is positive . Isn't it enough ?

Comment: It is the domain that is compact then, not the function. (and you *almost* had that anyway with "closed interval"). And look again at my example. $M$ being positive is not enough. M has to be at least as great as the biggest negative/positive slope of $F$ in magnitude before $F(x) \pm Mx$ is monotone.